# Alphabetize a list by the nth character

Tags: ruby

> Write a function that accepts two parameters, i) a string (containing a list of words) and ii) an integer (n). The function should alphabetize the list based on the nth letter of each word.

I have tried

```
def sort_it(list_, n)
  list_.sort_by {|name| name[n]}
end
```

but it is saying that `sort_by` is not recognised.

Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Comment: The error is because the first argument is a string, not an array? It's unclear what this method is supposed to do.

Comment: What is the format of the string containing a list of words?

Comment: What is "alphabetize"?

Comment: Are all words in the list at least as long as n? If not, what do you mean by the nth letter when the word is shorter?

Comment: Thank you, i apologise for the unclear instructions. This was a question on codewars.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have a start but need to show input data, how you call the method and your expected output. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list_` is a string while `sort_by` is a method of `Enumerable`. You need to convert your string to a collection of words before sorting. One way to do that is

`list_.split`

so your code will look like

```
def sort_it(list_, n)
  list_.split.sort_by {|name| name[n]}
end
```

As a side note, don't use trailing underscore in argument name.

Comment: Thank you - i have had a few other issue with this, but this is a great place to start